# Dynamic sql inside stored Procedure-sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below when i tried to execute throw an error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure CallView, Line 11
>   Invalid object name '#table'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallView]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
declare @name as varchar (max)

select @name = VIEW_NAME from ZBT_MAPPING_TABLE MT
INNER JOIN OUTPUT_DL DL ON MT.COMPID = DL.COMPID


-- insert to temp table
INSERT INTO #table
 (
    customerID,
    PRODUCT,
    PRODUCT_PRICE
    )
EXEC (N'select * from ' + @name)
```

when i execute it

```
exec [dbo].[CallView]
```

it throwing error as

> Invalid object name '#table'.**

may someone please suggest what is going wrong here and how can we rectify it.
Thanks

Comment: create temp table (#table) is missing

Comment: @sagi: i am trying to push data into temp table.

Comment: @StackUser: Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallView]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(max)

CREATE TABLE #table (
    customerID INT Identity(1, 1)
    ,PRODUCT VARCHAR(100)
    ,PRODUCT_PRICE DECIMAL(18, 2)
    )

SELECT @name = VIEW_NAME
FROM ZBT_MAPPING_TABLE MT
INNER JOIN OUTPUT_DL DL ON MT.COMPID = DL.COMPID

-- insert to temp table
INSERT INTO #table (
    customerID
    ,PRODUCT
    ,PRODUCT_PRICE
    )
EXEC (N'select * from ' + @name)

select *from  #table

drop table  #table
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the temp table `#table` first before using it

Add something like below before `Insert`

```
Create Table #table
(
    customerID int Identity(1,1),
    PRODUCT varchar(100),
    PRODUCT_PRICE Decimal(18,2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this whitout creating a temp table

```
select * 
into #table
from MyTable
```

but not

```
INSERT INTO #table
(
  customerID,
  PRODUCT,
  PRODUCT_PRICE
)
```

Comment: In fact the syntax is: `select * into #table from MyTable`
Anyway, if the table is already available, `INSERT ... EXEC` should work.

Comment: @Lucbert you are right, I'm sorry. What I mean is that select ... into #tmp is possible without creating, but insert into no